# Image upload to Instagram Business Account sometime returns "Only photo or video can be accepted as media type." with subcode 2207052 error message

Tags: java, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am trying to publish an image through Instagram API using java, the functionality working fine usually but sometimes the image failed to published with the error
`Only photo or video can be accepted as media type.` with subcode `2207052`

i checked in the docs
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/error-codes/

where i found the reason for this subcode is
*The media could not be fetched from this uri: {uri}

The media could not be fetched from the supplied URI. Advise the app user to make sure the URI is valid and publicly available.*

and i'm providing media url from s3 bucket file that is accessible and the image is also in JPEG format and supported.

can anyone help, what could be the reason?

```
params.add(Parameter.with("image_url", s3Url));
params.add(Parameter.with("caption", postText));
                                params.add(Parameter.with("access_token", access_token));
params.add(Parameter.with("user_tags", String.format("[%s]", StringUtils.join(userTags, ","))));

BatchRequest mediaRequest = new BatchRequest
                                        .BatchRequestBuilder(String.format("%s/media", socialNetworkId))
                                        .parameters(params.toArray(Parameter[]::new))
                                        .method("POST")
                                        .build();
```

after getting mediaId from above request, publishing it through another request using media id

```
BatchRequest batchRequestWrapper = new BatchRequest
                .BatchRequestBuilder(String.format("%s/media_publish", socialNetwrokId))
                .parameters(`your text`
                        Parameter.with("creation_id", mediaId),
                        Parameter.with("access_token", access_token)
                )
                .method("POST")
                .build();
```

Comment: Hello, if this error occurs only occasionally then I would implement some retry logic.